# Replacing associated values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a SQL Db that I am trying to query, consisting of three tables - Members, Bookings, and Facilities (country club stuff)

There is a memid column associated with each member, for which I have a first and a last name, and also who recommended them, recommendedby. Recommendedby is utilizing this memid, and I need to replace the number representing memid in recommendedby with The actual name of the person who recommended them. Any idea how I'd do this?

Here's a screenshot of the database:

[Screenshot of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1XhO.png)

As you can see, the first/surname columns are the names of the people, and each one of them is represented by a memid, and then that same memid is used to identify who recommended them, and again I need to replace those numbers in recommendedby with the actual name of the recommending member.

Comment: Paste table structures as `CREATE TABLE` statements or as link to some snippet ([for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) and data as `INSERT` statement or as tabular formatted text. No one wants to retype all that data from screenshot to create a statement. Also check formatting help in top-right corner of question input field and use "insert image" button for image embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a self-join:

```
select m.*, 
    r.surname   recommendedby_surname, 
    r.firstname recommendedby_firstname
from members m
inner join members r on r.memid = r.recommendedby
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! With a few modifications to what you wrote, this is exactly what I needed:

```SELECT m.firstname, m.surname, (r.surname || ' ' || r.firstname) AS recommendedby FROM Members as m INNER JOIN Members AS r ON m.memid = r.recommendedby ORDER BY m.surname, m.firstname```